# Revamp custom list view in webpart

Tags: custom-list, css, client-side-rendering

Morning guys

We currently use a really simple custom list to do our internal comms....[Image], [Title], [higlight], [story] are the fields.

When the view is displayed it renders as the normal view....

Read a lot about CSR but being a a complete novice I am struggling with it.   Can anyone help with a solution I can work back from to help understand how it works?

We basically want to display the image to the left, the title and highlight to the left centred title about the highlight, the user then clicks on the image to be taken to full comm in the new modal window.

Any help (with as much info so I can understand what it's doing and hopefully learn) would be greatly received...